# Chrome extension - How to pass a variable to new tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My background page saves data about the current active tab to `chrome.storage.local`. For arguments sake lets say it's the page title. Multiple page titles will be in there if the user has multiple tabs open.

When the browser action button is clicked I want to open a new tab with my internal extension page `showthedata.html` (not an external URL) which will show the data saved for the active tab.

Ideally I'd want to open `showthedata.html?tabID=123` which would then pull the corresponding data

I must be missing something basic, but how can `showthedata.html` show the data relating to the active tab?

Comment: You can use ?tabId URL if instead of declaring default_popup in manifest.json you use chrome.browserAction.onClicked event in the background script. In the listener just use chrome.tabs.create with the URL. See the documentation for details. It's also possible to pass data via messaging, there are many examples, but the simplest approach is probably to save the tab id in chrome.storage.local too.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I maybe wasn't clear. The new page I'm opening is a page within my extension, not external, hence not being able to use parameters (or can Ii?). I'll update question to clarify

Comment: You know what, I was under the impression I couldn't access parameters in a URL without it being a server side page, but that's not true. I can use some JS on showthedata.html to look at the parameter. Should I delete the question or add my own answer or neither?

Answer (score 3):

If you use your extension's URI as the URL of your new tab, it will allow you to use the API's messaging and storage systems from your new tab.

**Create a New Tab**

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome-extension://<your_extension_id>/path/to/file.html"})
```

Once you get that set up, you can pass variables to or request variables from your new tab via the Chrome API messaging system or storage system (provided you've built the proper functionality into your extension's various parts).

**Note:** The *chrome.tabs* namespace is not accessible from within a Chrome tab. It must be called from either your background script(s) or popup.